# How to add value from previous row to the next row in a new column in powerquery?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to create a new column in my grouped data which contains data value from the previous month. I found a solution [here](https://exceltown.com/en/tutorials/power-bi/powerbi-com-and-power-bi-desktop/power-bi-data-sources/power-query-get-value-from-previous-row/) but I am not able to use it for my problem because I am grouping the data and I want a solution which can be applied to a table for each group. To elaborate further my grouped data looks like

[image]

And the table looks like
[image]

My M code in power query looks like

```
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Sorted Rows", {"Attribute", "Marketing_year"}, {{"Var", (t) => Table.FromColumns(
            Table.ToColumns(t) & {List.Transform(t[Data], each _/List.Last(t[Data]))},
            {"Attribute", "Marketing_year", "Marketing_month", "Data", "Variation"}
    )}}),
```

Is there a way for me to add an additional column ("Data_previous_month") in my grouped data where the value is the value of data for previous month. For example, in row two of the new column "Data_previous_month" should be 19.41 in the table above, row three should have 19.17 so on and so forth.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the aggregation in the Table.Group function to add a shifted column, in addition to the variation column.  And don't forget to add a column Name for the new column.

```
//change `val` to `Data` to match what you have for column names
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Marketing_year"}, {
        {"Var", (t)=> Table.FromColumns(
            Table.ToColumns(t) & 
                {List.Transform(t[Val], each _/List.Last(t[Val]))} &
                {{null} & List.RemoveLastN(t[Val],1)},
                {"Marketing_year","Marketing_month", "Val", "Variation","Previous Month Val"}
    )}}),
```